# What is the pdf of $Y = \log X$?

Tags: probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a standard exponential random variable, and $Y = \log X$.

(a) Find DIRECTLY the c.d.f of $Y$ and use it to calculate the density of $Y$.

(b) Find DIRECTLY the p.d.f of $Y$.

---

So far, I did:

(a) $F_Y(y) = P(\log X \leq y) = P(X \leq e^y) = F_X(e^y)
f_Y(y) = F'_Y(y) = F'_X(e^y) = [f_X(e^y)][e^y] = (e^{-e^y})(e^y) = e^{y-e^y}$

(b) $f_Y(y) = P(\log X = y) = P(X = e^y) = f_X(e^y) = e^{-e^y}$

How come the answers I got for part a and b are not the same. What did I do wrong?

Comment: I can't seem to figure out how to use the MathJax syntax correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because PDFs don't work like this. The issue is you need to change of variables on the probability $P(Y=y)=f_Y(y)dy$, and not just the density. More precisely, if $y=\log(x)$ then $dy=e^{-y}dx$, so $P(Y=y)=f_Y(y)dy=P(\log X=y)=f_X(e^y)dx=f_X(e^y)e^ydy$ so that you recover your answer from the first part.

Comment: Sorry but the identity *$P(Y=y)=f_Y(y)dy$* is a monstrosity, which should be avoided at all cost.

Comment: If y = log x, then shouldn't dy = (1/x) dx?

Comment: @woaini $y=\log x\implies e^y=x\implies e^ydy=dx\implies dy=e^{-y}dx$. Both are correct, since $\frac 1x=e^{-y}$.

Comment: Just for future reference I believe that you need to use the pdf $f_{X>0}$ since  $Y=\log(X)$ is only defined when $X>0$. So $f_Y(y)=e^yf_{X>0}(e^y)=2e^2f_X(e^y)$. This pdf will integrate to $1$ over $\mathbb R$ however $f_X(e^y)e^y$ will only integrate to $\frac{1}{2}$ over $\mathbb R$. You could also consider $Y=\log|X|$ and here we would avoid needing to condition $X>0$ and we would again see that $f_Y(y)=2e^yf_X(e^y)$